# Replace only year isoDate from json mongo

Tags: javascript

I need to change the publishDate field every year, as shown in the json below, but for all documents in my collection. Only the year. I need to change from 2019, to 2020. Is it possible through a mongo java script?

```
    "urlHash": "-04020C193570E4B16326",
    "isDraft": true,

    "publishDate": {
      "$date": "2019-09-14T02:58:55.000Z"
    },
    "description": "",
    "mediaId": 16698520,
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use
db.collection.find().forEach(){ col.update() }

```
dbName.collectionName.find().forEach( (doc) => { 

 let date = doc.publishDate

 db.collectionName.update(
          {_id: doc._id}, 
          {$set: {   
                 publishDate: new Date(
                                       date.getYear()+1, 
                                       date.getMonth(),
                                       date.getDay(),
                                       date.getHours(),
                                       date.getMinutes(), 
                                       date.getSeconds(), 
                                       date.getMilliseconds()
                                       )
                  }
           })})
```

Comment: Tks Karl! Thank you very much!!!
In your example I'm just adding another year, in fact I would really like to be able to change the 4 digits of the year, for example if I want to put the year 1900.

Comment: yeah, so just replace the "date.getYear()+1" part to 1900 or any year and it has to be an integer